# Monotouch Threading - Better Design Question

Tags: multithreading, xamarin.ios

Often, I need to do an expensive task then display results. So I ramp up a thread. Is there less code, or a better way to doing this than I am currently using?

Example:

```
ThreadStart job = new ThreadStart (delegate {
    Search d = new Search ();
    x = d.DoSomeWork();
    InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {
         ctl.Show (x);
          });
});
```

--start the thread here....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the thread pool and simplify things a little bit.

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( delegate { /* ... */ } );

Comment: I also do it this way.. The trick is to never, never never forget the InvokeOnMainThread().

Comment: One thing to remember is the ThreadPool on Monotouch (because the maximum memory footprint of your app can be around 46mb) is limited to around 20 threads

Answer (score 4):

As Kevin points out, the use of the ThreadPool is slightly simpler.

But there is an added bonus to using the ThreadPool: Mono will limit the number of threads that you spin up, helping you better preserve the limited resources on the device.

Comment: Miguel, thanks for the answer..and for Monotouch!!! We've shipped 45 apps and sold several thousand all on the rock-solid Monotouch framework you and your team have built.